# encryption in PHP and decryption in node.js

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, encryption, character-encoding

I've tried suggestions and tricks by reading various answers on stack overflow but they don't seem to be sufficient or maybe there's something basic i'm missing. Basically i'm trying to encrypt a value in php and pass it to the webpage from where it's read by JavaScript and send to node server for processing. But i'm unable to get the same value back on node server which i encrypted in php.

Below is the php code and php version is 5.5.12 running on windows 7 64 bit:-

```
function encrypt($string){
 $key = hash("SHA256", '1d417e2ffb2a00a3', true);
 $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
 $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
 $blockSize = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
 $padding = $blockSize - (strlen($string) % $blockSize);
 $string .= str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);

 $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key,$string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
 $result['cipher'] = base64_encode($ciphertext);
 $result['iv'] = base64_encode($iv);
 return $result;
}
```

My node.js version is 0.10.31 running on windows 7 64 bit and code is below:-

```
var express = require("express");
var Server = require("http").Server;
var cookie = require("cookie");
var app = express();
var server = Server(app);
var sio = require("socket.io")(server);
var crypto = require('crypto');

sio.sockets.on("connection", function(socket) {
try{
        socket.on('incoming_data', function(data){
            var txt = new Buffer(data.encrypted_text,'base64');
            var key = new Buffer('1d417e2ffb2a00a3','utf8');
            var iv = new Buffer(data.iv,'base64');
            var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc',key,iv);
            var chunks = [];
            chunks.push(decipher.update(txt,'hex','binary'));
            chunks.push(decipher.final('binary'));
            var fuid = chunks.join('');
            console.log(fuid);
        });
    }catch(e){
        console.log("err:-"+e);
        console.log(e);
    }
});// on connection ends
server.listen(9267, function(){
  console.log('Node server listening on *:9267');
});

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  console.log("FATAL: "+new Date().getTime()+": "+err);
 });
```

The error i get from printing fuid in nodejs console is as below:-

```
FATAL: 1414483246855: TypeError: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
```

I am looking for solutions to the following in the answers:-

1) Problems with my code and what needs to be fixed to get back the same value on node server as a string.

2) Would like to concatenate the encrypted text and the iv and send them both as a single base64 encoded string to the server. So would like the code that will be needed to separate them back on node server ready to be passed to the crypto module.

3) This code seems vulnerable to oracle padding attacks. It will be great if you can suggest how can i make it secure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be with your encoding:

```
chunks.push(decipher.update(txt,'hex','binary'));
```

`hex` looks strange, since your inputs are buffers, not strings.

The following quick test works (also answers 2.):

php:

```
$key = 'secretsecretsecr';
$string = 'attack at dawn';

$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
$blockSize = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$padding = $blockSize - (strlen($string) % $blockSize);
$string .= str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);
$ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key,$string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

$packet = chr($iv_size) . $iv . $ciphertext;

print base64_encode($packet);
```

node:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var key = 'secretsecretsecr';
var data = 'paste what the php code printed';

var txt = new Buffer(data,'base64');
var iv_size = txt[0];
var iv = txt.slice(1, iv_size + 1);
var ct = txt.slice(iv_size + 1);
var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc',key,iv);
var chunks = [];
chunks.push(decipher.update(ct));
chunks.push(decipher.final());

console.log(chunks.join(''));
```

The passes the iv size along, you can also simply hardcode it on the node side.

Regarding 3), I am by no means an expert, from what I've read the workaround is to sign your encrypted packets with HMAC to make sure they're coming from your application and not from the "oracle" (http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-mcgrew-aead-aes-cbc-hmac-sha2-05.txt).

Comment: with regards to hex as input encoding i left it there because node documentation says that if the input is a buffer then the provided encoding is ignored. This seems to be a version issue maybe. what environment you tested on ?

Comment: @Avdhesh: PHP 5.3.6 / Ubuntu, node v0.11.12 / OSX Mavericks.

Comment: my bad. actually i'm getting the same error as earlier "FATAL: 1414489055585: TypeError: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt"

Comment: @Avdhesh: do you run these codes exactly as posted?

Comment: I checked again and it seems i hashed the key before using it in php. So no. I've now done it exactly as per the code you posted above and it works successfully. Thanks a lot and my apologies for the confusion. You are the man

Comment: just for the sake of curiosity and self improvement i'd like to know did you deduce that the key is not to be hashed in php. was it by err n trial or previous experience.

Comment: @Avdhesh: this is simple debugging practices: put together the simplest code that works, removing all non-essential features. Keep adding features until it breaks.